# bNiceArray doesn’t show first-row

Tags: nicematrix

I have the following `bNiceArray` environment:

```
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{S}_{Mi} =
  \begin{bNiceArray}{cccccccccccc}[first-row,first-col,code-for-first-col=\mathbf{\arabic{iRow}},code-for-first-row=\arabic{jCol}]
    & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    & \frac{EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0 & -\frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} \\
    & & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0 & -\frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0 & -\frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
    & & & & \frac{GJ}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{GJ}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
    & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 & \frac{2EI_y}{L} & 0 \\
    & & & & & & \frac{4EI_z}{L} & 0 & -\frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2EI_z}{L} \\
    & & & & & & & \frac{EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{6EI_z}{L^2} \\
    & & & & & & & & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & & & \frac{GJ}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L} & 0 \\
    & \emph{sim.} & & & & & & & & & & & \frac{4EI_z}{L}
  \end{bNiceArray}
  \label{eq:stiffness_matrix}
\end{equation}
```

But the first row doesn’t appear. Any ideas ?

[image]

**edit**

I want to get this:

[image]

I handwrite the first row but the style with the column numbers doesn’t match.

```
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{S}_{Mi} =
  \begin{bNiceArray}{cccccccccccc}[small,first-col,first-row,code-for-first-col=\mathbf{\arabic{iRow}},code-for-first-row=\mathbf{}]
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
    & \frac{EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0 & -\frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} \\
    & & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0 & -\frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0 & -\frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
    & & & & \frac{GJ}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{GJ}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
    & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 & \frac{2EI_y}{L} & 0 \\
    & & & & & & \frac{4EI_z}{L} & 0 & -\frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2EI_z}{L} \\
    & & & & & & & \frac{EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{6EI_z}{L^2} \\
    & & & & & & & & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & & & \frac{GJ}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L} & 0 \\
    & \emph{sim.} & & & & & & & & & & & \frac{4EI_z}{L}
  \end{bNiceArray}
  \label{eq:stiffness_matrix}
\end{equation}
```

**solved**

I run the document again and it's working like a charm.

[image]

Comment: With the `first-row` option the first row is printed outside of the matrix brackets. This also happens in your code, you just don't see it because your first row consists only of empty cells. Which output did you want/expect exactly? Maybe you can add a second screenshot that you have edited in a graphics editor like Paint or equivalent that shows your desired output.

Comment: I added `code-for-first-row=\arabic{jCol}` to put to each column a number, but nothing appear.

Answer (score 5):

Note: this answer applies to version 4.4 or earlier of nicematrix. Starting with version 5.0 (July 15th 2021) the column specification is provided in lower case.

---

The column specifications need to be provided with upper case letters. From the `nicematrix` manual:

> However, for technical reasons, in the preamble of the environment
> `{NiceArray}`, the user must use the letters `L`, `C` and `R` instead
> of `l`, `c` and `r`

In this case that means `\begin{bNiceArray}{CCCCCCCCCCCC}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{S}_{Mi} =
  \begin{bNiceArray}{CCCCCCCCCCCC}[first-row,first-col,code-for-first-col=\mathbf{\arabic{iRow}},code-for-first-row=\arabic{jCol}]
    & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    & \frac{EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0 & -\frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} \\
    & & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0 & -\frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0 & -\frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
    & & & & \frac{GJ}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{GJ}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
    & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 & \frac{2EI_y}{L} & 0 \\
    & & & & & & \frac{4EI_z}{L} & 0 & -\frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2EI_z}{L} \\
    & & & & & & & \frac{EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{6EI_z}{L^2} \\
    & & & & & & & & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & & & \frac{GJ}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L} & 0 \\
    & \emph{sim.} & & & & & & & & & & & \frac{4EI_z}{L}
  \end{bNiceArray}
  \label{eq:stiffness_matrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: For information: It's in version 5.0 of `nicematrix` (2020-07-15) that the letters `R`, `L` and `C` in the preamble of `{pNiceArray}` have been replaced by the more standard letters `r`, `l` and `c`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny I see it is listed in the changelog in the manual, I should have looked better :)